# Trouble understanding the @ variable in update query

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Me again. I have trouble understanding the @variables located in a query.

ex:

```
UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id
```

I'm trying to upgrade the date from a gridview that has the AutoGenerateEditButton to True. Here is the aspx file:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gv1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CellPadding="2"
                    DataKeyNames="id"
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                    OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowDeleted="gv1_RowDeleted"
                    OnRowUpdating="gv1_RowUpdating">
                </asp:GridView>
```

and this is the function that the OnRowUpdating function calls:

```
 protected void gv1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (strType)
            {
                case "servers":
                    Response.Write("1");
                    break;
                case "systems":
                    DS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id";
                    break;
                case "itOwners":
                    Response.Write("3");
                    break;
                case "systemOwners":
                    Response.Write("4");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            gv1.EditIndex = -1;
            gv1.DataSourceID = DS.ID;
            gv1.DataBind();
        }
```

I've been testing a couple of things without any success.

Tried to:

- add Systems to the DatakeyNames. This prevents the textbox to be created in the Gridview.
- did a add Systems parameter to the SqlDataSource. This gives me an error telling me that Systems variable already existes.
- Get the information in the Gridview edit textbox without any success. Aways getting the original value not the new one.

Here are some of my questions:

1. Should the DataKeyNames used only to identify primary keys?
2. How do I get the information entered in the textbox created by the edit option of the gridview?
3. How do I get  or set the information in the @variables?

Thanks,

Comment: They are parameters, See: [SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Parameters are used as a placeholder of sorts to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

**1.Should the DataKeyNames used only to identify primary keys?**

yes

**2.How do I get the information entered in the textbox created by the edit option of the gridview?**

you have to make a post back and then you can retrieve them from the gridview object.

**3.How do I get or set the information in the @variables?**

these are variables for parameters to send to the database , works something like this

```
string sql = "UPDATE tbSystems SET Systems = @Systems WHERE id = @id";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
             param.ParameterName = "@Systems";
             param.Value         = systems;

command.Parameters.Add(param);

SqlParameter paramId  = new SqlParameter();
             paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
             paramId.Value         = Id;

command.Parameters.Add(paramId);
```

Edit, showing creation of parameter objects.

Comment: `.AddWithValue()` has been known to be problematic. I'd recommend using the `Parameters.Add().Value` alternative instead.

Comment: From there shouldn't I just open the connection, Execute the SqlCommand and close the connection? I've put static values to test and It doesn't change the value in my DB.

Comment: getting this error now: Must declare the scalar variable "@Systems".

Comment: try remove the @ in the parametername

Comment: Did that. Added this in the SQL string: DECLARE Systems varchar(50) SET Systems = 'Test'. No more errors but ain't getting the information from the textbox. always getting the old value. You mentioned getting the info from the post back. can you start me on this?

Comment: The systems in the declarations have @

Comment: Looking in the GridViewUpdateEventArgs e, the oldValue and the newValue are the same. Both have the old value. Is this expected?